# Unable to get payload from action in reducer inside react native app?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to get a json response from an api and get the data successfully but when I call a action within another action using redux-thunk, my data is not available inside the reducer. **I need data in "data" property inside my reducer get in component**. Check the code below.

This is my action

```js
import { GET_REPORT, GET_DATA_SUCCESS } from './types';

export const getData = (text) => {
    
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch ({ type: GET_REPORT})
        fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='+text+'&cnt=1&units=metric&APPID={key}')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => getDataSuccess(dispatch, data.list[0]))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    };
};

const getDataSuccess = (dispatch, data) => {
    //console.log(data);
    dispatch({
        type: GET_DATA_SUCCESS,
        payload: data
    });
}
```

this is my reducer

```js
import { GET_REPORT } from'../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    data: '',
}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_REPORT:
            console.log(action.payload); // getting undefined
            return {...state, data: action.payload};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I need data in "data" property get in component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by adding new switch case for GET_DATA_SUCCESS and get the payload from getDataSuccess and removing the payload from GET_REPORT case.
Now switch case looks like this

```js
switch(action.type){
        case GET_REPORT:
            return {...state};
        case GET_DATA_SUCCESS:
            console.log(action.payload);
            return{...state, data: action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are missing GET_DATA_SUCCESS in your reducer

Answer (score 1):

The action `dispatch ({ type: GET_REPORT})` , doesn't contain a payload hence `undefined`. Either you need to make reducer to handle action `GET_DATA_SUCCESS` or modify the existing one.

To simplify, `dispatch({
        type: GET_DATA_SUCCESS,
        payload: data
    });` contains a payload whereas `dispatch ({ type: GET_REPORT})` doesn't

Comment: Not Working, I want payload from getDataSuccess action . First my app calls getData action then it return a json response data to getDataSuccess then it should return data as payload to reducer. But I am getting undefined.

Comment: Check your reducer file, action `GET_REPORT` doesn't dispatch any payload, it's that simple